# Native linking failed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

i am try to compile my xamarin.ios in release build.  i use 'Link SDK assemblies only' with some additional mtouch arguments '-cxx' and '-gcc_flags' to link library,but get the following errors:

```
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kUTTagClassFilenameExtension. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kUTTypeBundle. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _UTTypeConformsTo. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioComponentFindNext. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioComponentInstanceNew. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioUnitUninitialize. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioUnitSetProperty. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioOutputUnitStop. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioUnitRender. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioUnitInitialize. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioConverterNew. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioOutputUnitStart. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kUTTypeTIFF. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioComponentInstanceDispose. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioServicesPlayAlertSound. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
```

I have tried different configuration for ios build setting:

1. 'link sdk assemblies only' in release mode but get same errors
2. 'link sdk assemblies only' in debug mode but get same errors
3. 'link all assemblies' in release mode but get same errors
4. 'link all assemblies' in debug mode but get same errors
5. 'no link' in release mode, it install on my phone but my app quit unexpectedly as long as i open it.
6. 'no link' in debug mode, everything is ok and i can run my app on my phone

i cannot find any useful information about these errors. could anyone help me?

Comment: Hi, whehter have a try with Link all assemblies to check whether it works?

Answer (score -1):

Check your `Xamarin.iOS` project [Linker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i use different configuration for linker as i have mentioned in my question. but still   get  these errors...what confused me was that only when i use no link in debug build, everything seems ok and i can run my app